# React scrollIntoView moves page only a little, not to the specified element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to scroll a page to specified `div` when the page loads. So here is my code to achieve the goal

```js
    const ref = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
        if (node !== null) {
            node.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
        }
    }, [])


    return (
      <div>
        //content
        <div ref={ref}/>
      </div>
    )
```

but the page moves only a litle (about dozens of pixels from the top) when it loads but not to the specified element. When the any state on the page changes, then it moves to the specified element while I want this action on the first render.

Here is the screen of scrollbar place on the page after first render to better visualise what I mean saying that page moves only a little.

[image]

The scrollbar should be almost at the bottom where the specified `div` is placed while its just some pixes from the top od page.

Comment: Hello. Do you have any minimal reproducible example of your issue? Like codesandbox?

Comment: here is the sanbox with the page code
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-paper-i7n72o?file=/src/App.js

however, I pasted only a jsx code. I would need to import many libraries and copy paste many of the components to let this work

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a `useRef` to reference the element you want to scroll to and a `useEffect` to trigger the scroll when the component mounts.

```js
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const ref = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (ref.current === null) return;
  ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    //content
    <div ref={ref} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I tried this in many ways and it does not work, beacuase the ref element inside useEffect is null. Its described in this article https://tkdodo.eu/blog/avoiding-use-effect-with-callback-refs

Comment: I created this simplified [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-water-tg8p6w) and both methods work fine @user123145152323

Comment: it started working when I specified height of the upper component. 
However I would like to avoid this